# Using floating point addition in verilog

Tags: verilog

How can I represent floating point numbers in Verilog?

I am trying to use following code to do floating point addition but I am seeing integer as a output:

```
real r1,r2,r3;

initial begin
    r1 = 1.1;
    r2 = 1.2;
    r3 = r1+ r2;
    $display("Print the output %b", r3);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`%b` indicates that a result should be print as `binary`. If you want to display a float number, you should use `%e` indicator.

```
$display("Print the output %e", r3);
```

Result before the change:

```
Print the output 00000000000000000000000000000010
```

and after:

```
Print the output 2.300000e+00
```

Comment: Thanks Qiu, Is there any way to print the output in 32bit binary form?

Comment: @naveenkumar: [here](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/verilog/system.html) you can find available format indicators.